# Passing Parameter with ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass parameters from a list that is being populated from Cloud firestore.

My `home.ts` file with properties and method for getting a single post from postID.

```
  post: Observable<Post>;
  postDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Post>;

  getPost(postId) {

    this.postDoc = this.afs.doc('posts/' + postId);
    this.post = this.postDoc.valueChanges();
    this.navCtrl.push( SinglePostPage, {
       singlePost: this.post
  } );
  }
```

On single post page template

```
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      {{ ( singlePost | async)?.title }}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
       {{ ( singlePost | async)?.content }}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

For my `singlepost.ts`

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.navParams = this.navParams.get('singlePost');
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the contents of `this.post`?

Comment: Is for providing observable from `this.postDoc`

Comment: My question being, does `this.post` contain a property `singlePost`?

Comment: Updated the file.

Comment: when you're retrieving this object `this.navParams.get('singlePost')`. What is its value??

Comment: It's values is "this.post" from the observable.